# how to change the value of two different type input tags. so that the value is always the same as real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input tags, one type number and one type range (slider).
how can the values of the two remain the same when changing the value through the input number or input type range (slider)?
I can only change from just one tag, it can't go through both tags.

```
<input type="text" id="rangevalue" value="5" oninput="priceSlider()" />
<div id="myslider1" class="slider" type="range" ></div>

<script>
$(function () {
        $("#myslider1").slider({`
            range: "min",
            value: 5,
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#rangevalue").val(ui.value);
            }`
        });
        $("#rangevalue").val($("#myslider1").slider("value"));
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to bind the `change` event to the `input` element to update the slider each time it is changed by replacing:

```
$("#rangevalue").val($("#myslider1").slider("value"));
```

with

```
$('#rangevalue').on('change', function(e) {
    $("#myslider1").slider("value", this.value)
})
```

Here's a working example which assumes you are using jQuery UI. I have used `keyup` in place of `change` for an instantaneous update.

```js
$("#myslider1").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 5,
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#rangevalue").val(ui.value);
    }
});

$('#rangevalue').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $("#myslider1").slider("value", this.value)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="rangevalue" value="5" />
<div id="myslider1" class="slider" type="range" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both now fully in sync.

```js
let changing = false;
const syncRange = (slider) => { 
    if(changing === false) {
      changing = true;
      document.querySelector('#rangevalue').setAttribute('value', parseInt(slider.value));
      changing = false;
     }
};

const syncSlider = (range) => {
    if(changing === false) {
      changing = true;
      document.querySelector('#slider1').value = parseInt(range.value);
      changing = false;
    }
};


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#slider1')
          .addEventListener('change', event => syncRange(event.target));
  
  document.querySelector('#rangevalue')
          .addEventListener('keyup', (event) => syncSlider(event.target)); 
          
  syncSlider(document.querySelector('#rangevalue'));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="rangevalue" value="5" />
<div id="myslider1" class="slider" type="range" >
  <input id="slider1" type='range' min='0' max='100' />
</div>
```

Comment: Are there other solutions using jquery.ui as I have made?